# Does Ichigo still have his powers after his battle with Yhwach?

Tags: bleach

The final chapter of the manga shows Ichigo leading a normal life but it's never really shown if he is still a Shinigami. Or is it the same as the time he used the Final Getsuga Tenshou in his fight with Aizen? Has Kubo talked about this somewhere, given how abrupt the ending was?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, the 2 Novels following the manga's ending said that he regained the powers stolen by Yhwach.

Comment: Welcome to [anime.se]. Thanks for answering the question. Meanwhile, could you add the name of the 2 novels and explain a little more when Ichigo regained the powers (e.g. what page, the scene regarding this, etc). You can [edit] your answer to improve it! Also, consider taking a [tour] to understand more how this site works!

Comment: To add to that single line answers do tend to end up in the delete queue more often than they should. I'm flagging this as ok. But please try to keep a 3 sentence minimum. Decent answers shouldn't end up here. Especially if they are correct.